# can 'net6.0' project be referenced by a project that targets '.NETStandard 2.0'?

Tags: reference, .net-6.0, .net-standard-2.0

Error:

> Project 'XXX.csproj' targets 'net6.0-windows'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'

Any solution?

I have .NET 6 project with some Windows Forms, and want to access it in .NET Standard 2.0 project.
Getting above error.